# Include/Where VS Where/Include EF MVC Performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, optimization

Will EF intelligently interpret a Query ordered `Include().Where()` to have the same run time as `Where().Include()`?

Meaning will

```
var myObjects = db.Objects.Include(o => o.ObjectReference).Where(o => o.intField == intVar);
```

have the same run time as

```
var myObjects = db.Objects.Where(o => o.intField == intVar).Include(o => o.ObjectReference);
```

because it only loads in both cases after the Where or is the first slower because first it loads then filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There "shouldn't" be any difference in the generated query that is produced by Linq to Entities.  Check out this similar SO question and answer.

[C# linq include before-after where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685069/c-sharp-linq-include-before-after-where)