# When using Entity Framework Core to access a database, does the order of .Where and .Include calls matter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Consider the following sequences of calls.

**Include-first version:**

```
                 var smiths = dbContext.Person
                .Include(_ => _.Country)
                .Where(_ => _.LastName == "Smith")
                .ToList();
```

**Where-first version:**

```
                 var smiths = dbContext.Person
                .Where(_ => _.LastName == "Smith")
                .Include(_ => _.Country)
                .ToList();
```

Is one better than the other? Does it matter?

More than the simple toy example above, I'm interested in whether or not it matters to have a habit of doing it one way or the other. In practice, the .Include trees may be large.

Comment: it doesn't matter as the compiler will parse the hole thing in one goal and the parser will pick every line at te same time

Comment: Already answered here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685069/c-sharp-linq-include-before-after-where

Comment: It should and does not matter. `Include` is just instruction what to load.